is there any microsoft site, like passwords.google.com?
is there any microsoft site, like https://passwords.google.com, to view all my saved sites passwords stored in my personal microsoft account, accessible with any browser, without any specific tool?
I searched many FAQs.
I've already asked this question on a Microsoft site
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-there-any-microsoft-site-like/777a8bf6-dd7f-4e7b-801c-8bc9411bfa99
but with no helpful answers.
It seems strange to me that it isn't there, if I can connect to Edge and have all the passwords it means that these passwords, although encrypted, are available on the Microsoft servers.

Your passwords are stored locally within Edge.

@Ramhound: Unless they're synced to a Microsoft account.

@grawity - My Edge profile is configured to synchronize with my MSA but when I investigate this my passwords were clearly only stored locally on my system. Now I might not have that option enabled, still don’t believe, there is an setting within a MSA to display the passwords though.
